# Online fillable form with review feature by admin on Moodle

Tags: html, moodle, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have an immediate requirement of online HTML forms on Moodle which can be filled by students on Moodle and can be reviewed by Teacher or the Admin.

I was planning to make something like SCORM wrapped HTML forms but I don't think Moodle allows teacher or the admin to review what the students have filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Feedback module? https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Feedback_module